# Electron JS and TypeScript - Using TS-Node with main process

Tags: typescript, electron, ts-node

How would you adjust the following script to allow electron main process to use Typescript with ts-node?

```
"scripts": {
     "shell": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron ts-node ./app/main.ts"
}
```

Comment: Isn't it more a question of doing
`cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node electron ./app/main.ts`? I am asking because I haven't really tried it out, but seems logical. Otherwise you have to look at something like `ts-node/register`

Answer (score 6):

`cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron -r ts-node/register ./app/main.ts`

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#programmatic

> You can require ts-node and register the loader for future requires by using require('ts-node').register({ /* options */ }). You can also use file shortcuts - node -r ts-node/register or node -r ts-node/register/transpile-only - depending on your preferences.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

While using `electron -r ts-node/register` works for simple cases, you can also have your script point to a bootscript JavaScript file that just does this:

```
require('ts-node').register()
require('./app/main')
```

The benefit of doing this is that you can specify ts-node options. Necessary for e.g. monorepos, where you might to something like `require('ts-node').register({ project: './app/tsconfig.json' })`.

See the ts-node docs for options that can be specified: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/api/interfaces/RegisterOptions.html